# CSS animation lag on Android Cordova app

Tags: css, cordova, animation, web, ionic-framework

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0;
animation-delay: 0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

Why would a `<div>` with the above css applied to it experience lag when animated? This is inside a Cordova app, the animation is extremely clean and smooth on iOS, but seriously lags in Android. Other elements in my app on Android are animating very smooth, its just this element. I'm hardware accelerating, using transforms etc... but just no luck. Here is the animation being used on the elements:

```
@keyframes slideInRight {
  from {
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: How good animations are running depends of the webview in the device.On older androids animations are not running very good and there are some manufacturer which have a modified webkit version.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test with the Crosswalk WebView Engine ?

cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: Yes, I am using crosswalk.